# Binding not finding source with reference (MenuItem)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am getting the error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=gridProductViewDataGrid'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')

In the Output window of visual studio and my code doesnt do what it is supposed to do.

The add works fine because it is never needing to be disabled but the remove is not being disabled.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="gridViewProductDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" >
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding LabelStrings.AddProductLabel, Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}}" Click="Add_Product_MenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding LabelStrings.RemoveProductLabel, Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}}" Click="Remove_Product_MenuItem_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=gridViewProductDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToBooleanConverter}}"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Where the converter simply takes returns true if there is no object and false if it exists.
I have tried moving this code in and out of the grid as well as moving parts of the binding in different orders. When I run the the code and put in a break point, it never went into the code for the boolean converter. Why cant it see the grid when it is inside it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ContextMenu is opened on a different Visual Tree then his parent, and therefore Named Binding won't work.

Try something like this:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.SelectedItem, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}, 
                    Converter={StaticResource ObjectToBooleanConverter}}"
```

Which uses the ContextMenu's `PlacementTarget` (which is the DataGrid) to get the correct DataContext.

Another option is to set the `NameScope` for the ContextMenu. Add the following line to your CodeBehind:

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(contextMenu, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
```

Where `contextMenu` is the Name you gave your ContextMenu

Comment: I have now managed to get a new error     `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PlacementTarget' property not found on 'object' ''GridViewProductUserControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.SelectedItem; DataItem='GridViewProductUserControl' (Name=''); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')`

Comment: Right, I didn't notice you're setting this on a MenuItem - I updated my answer with a RelativeSource to the ContextMenu.

Comment: Brilliant!  But, I had to drop the 'DataContext' part to be able to bind to the DataGrid's SelectedItem value:  <MenuItem IsEnabled="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem.bMyTrueOrFalseField...>

Comment: How'd you achieve the same when the `MenuItem` is in a `Menu` and not on a `ContextMenu`?